# How do I add a new ROM/ Moto G 2013?

Tags: motorola

I was flashing a new ROM to my Moto G and I accidentally put a normal file instead of a ZIP file. I accidentally wiped the OS off the phone and I can't get the ROM back onto the phone. Not Sure What To Do. Moto G 2013 I also used twrp

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have the zip file on the internal storage of the phone or sdcard. Go to recovery and press install zip and then select the ROM zip and install it. Also you may want to wipe cache , data and dalvik cache before installing zip.

This is a bit searchable stuff you should not ask this types of questions , first you can search on Google or search on this very website about similar questions, that will help keeping out duplicate questions , hope you understand me.